# Character restriction in html form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

Can anyone help me to implement the JavaScript correctly in my HTML, so that it is not possible to write `,'*+?` in my login and password form?

My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<script> 
var Username =/[A-Za-z]/g;
var Password = /[A-Za-z]/g;

function restrictCharacters(myfield, e, restrictionType) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event
    if (e.keyCode) code = e.keyCode;
    else if (e.which) code = e.which;
    var character = String.fromCharCode(code);

    if (code==27) { this.blur(); return false; }

    if (!e.ctrlKey && code!=9 && code!=8 && code!=36 && code!=37 && code!=38 && (code!=39 || (code==39 && character=="'")) && code!=40) {
        if (character.match(restrictionType)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
<body>
<form>

    <input type="text" name="Username" id="Username">
    <input type="Password" name=Password" id="Password" method="POST">
    <input type="Submit" name="Login" id="Login">


</form>


</body>
</html>
```

It would be awesome, if you can help!

Comment: I'm curious as to why you want to do this?

Comment: It's not a good idea to prevent what characters people can use in their passwords.

Comment: I hope what you want is server-side set somewhere? -> Nothing to stop someone from disabling JS and going full-out ",'*+?,'*+?" Also, what @Scimonster said, the more random chars allowed in a password the better it gets

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple example how to do this

```
<input type="text"  onkeypress="return filter(event)"/>

 <script>
    function filter(evt)
    {   
       var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
       if ( charCode ==43 || charCode ==44  || charCode ==39 || charCode ==63 || charCode ==42  ) return false;
    }
 </script>
```

but you should validate all inputs on the server side.